# Kendo grid column lock issue

Tags: kendo-ui, grid, locking, freeze

I have a big problem with a Kendo grid when locking columns. The grid has two static columns and one or more columns created dynamically. Without locking any column, the grid works just fine, when i'm locking the static columns (or just one of them), the grid goes mad. 
I know that locking columns will create two different tables (with locked and unlocked columns) but in my case, these tables (with different divs) won't align in my page.

I tried to align them manually using CSS (display:inline-block and/or float: left) but when I resize the window, the grid comes back to the wrong form.

I attached two examples:
[image: Without locking]
[image: With locking]

In the second example, the rest of the columns are situated somewhere under the page (i need to zoom out to see them).

Inserted simplified code (without locked applied)

Code for columns:

```
       var columns = [
{
    field: "Field_Locked1",
    title: "F1",
    editor: "",
    attributes: { style: "text-align: left;" },
    sortable: false,
    footerTemplate: "T",
    width: "30px"
    },
    {
        field: "Field_locked2",
        title: "F2",
        editable: false,
        attributes: { style: "text-align: left;" },
        template: "#=test(string)#",
        footerTemplate: "<div style='text-align: right;'>1</div><hr/><div style= 'text-align: right;'>2</div>",
        width: "370px",
        sortable: false
   }
];

   for (var i = 0; i < customColumns.length; i++) {
    var itemTab = customColumns[i];
   var dinamicColumn = {
       field: itemTab.Name,
       title: itemTab.Code,
       editable: false,
       type: "number",
       attributes: { style: "text-align: right;" },
       sortable: false,
       width: "200px",
       template: "#= test(string)#",
       footerTemplate: "<div style='text-align: right;'>1</div><hr/><div style= 'text-align: right;'>2</div>"
    };

    columns.splice(columns.length, 0, dinamicColumn);
}
```

Code for creating grid:

```
function createGridGeneric(tabElement,columns) {

    var gridModel = tabElement.templateDescription.grid;
    var idGrid = gridModel.id;
    var gridToolbal = gridModel.toolbar != null ? gridModel.toolbar:null;
    var gridFooter = gridModel.footer != null ? gridModel.footer : null;
    var hasArea = tabElement.filterArea != null ? tabElement.filterArea.visible : false;

    var grid = $("#" + idGrid).data("kendoGrid");
    if (grid != null) {
        $("#" + idGrid).empty();
    } 

    $("#" + idGrid).kendoGrid({
        autoBind: false,
        columns: columns,
        editable: false,
        filterable: false,
        groupable: false,
        selectable: false,
        sortable: false,
        scrollable: true,
        resizable: true,
        save: function(e) {
        },
        saveChanges: function(e) {
        },
        columnResize: function(e) {
            gridColumnResize(e);
        },
        databound: function(e) { }
     });
     return grid;
```

}

Comment: You should probably provide your grid configuration code so we can see what you are doing to create the grid.

Comment: I can't provide the code because it is dynamically created. I'll try to select some parts of the code. I'll try to update the question in a few minutes.

Comment: I updated with the code. I think that the problem is with the CSS. The area size where the grid is drawn become fixed when Locked property is applied to the grid and a window resize move my second divs (locked divs) under the first. Also, i'm using a template to create the grid, may this thing cause my problem?